# Is there a way to make a circular image in HTML using Canvas or other Method?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I know that the `canvas` element can look like a circle using the CSS `border-radius` property.  However, if you draw something using the canvas API, and then right-click to "Save as Image", when saved, the image is still a rectangle (as if the border-radius was not applied). Is there a way to actually save the correct image?

Answer (score 4):

All image formats that I know of yield rectangles.

You could draw a circle on a canvas with the outside of the circle being transparent.  That would visually look like a circle rather than a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

When css applies, it does not really transform the image except visually. So, you would need a bit more than simple css. The issue is discussed here where what you want is achieved using javascript:

[Save canvas image after css applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025596/save-canvas-image-after-css-applied)

[Capture and save an image with css effects applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270897/capture-save-export-an-image-with-css-filter-effects-applied)

Hope this helps.